# PHP Special character in property name of object

Tags: php, codeigniter, properties

I pull some data from oracle database to mysql and output is something like this:

- +"some name": "some value"
- +b"å½eljeno vrijeme": "some value"
- +"some name too": "some value"

I can't get **+b"å½eljeno vrijeme": "some value"**.

I tried **echo $someClass->{'å½eljeno vrijeme'}** but it doesn't work.

I got error **Undefined property: stdClass::$å½eljeno vrijeme**.

I noticed every object has + before but wanted object have +b before.

Comment: access it as array .. also, fix your encodings

Comment: I do it with laravel DB::connection('oracle')->select() function so thats the reason why is object and i can't change encodings.

Comment: That only makes it worse. Also, why exactly you tagged it with "codeigniter" then?

Comment: The +b before the strings means the string is binary, which I don't believe is the desired behaviour. You should really fix the encoding of your key, because I believe it's causing all of your problems